# Python script executed using asp dot net core Process.Start() can't find modules

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-core, pip, process

I made a web api and it runs a python script through the use of c# Process.Start(). The script works with no issues in localhost but once I deploy and publish it on IIS, I get this error from the python script.

```
line 281, in apply_affine_transform    raise ImportError("Image transformations require SciPy. "ImportError: Image transformations require SciPy. Install SciPy.
```

I checked the installed modules by doing "pip list -v" and sure enough, scipy was installed already. I then executed the script through cmd and it worked with no issues. I gathered that this would only occur if the python script was executed through the c# Process.Start()

**NOTE:** The error is thrown within another imported module, specifically in here :

```
C:\Users\Computer1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py\
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
I was not able to solve the problem but I found a workaround involving anaconda(https://www.anaconda.com/), which was to use Process.Start() to run the script through the conda (base) environment

Comment: I guess it's likely related to the IIS App Pool user not having access to SciPy or something

Comment: @CarlReid I suspect this too but I am unfamiliar on the process of providing the app pool access to scipy... I set it to run as "Local System" and gave it full permissions for the involved files, still didn't do anything... What's weird is that the import for tensorflow isn't raising an error although the command used for installing both modules were the same => "pip install <package_name>"